# How to call on change and on click event from a same class in Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have few checkboxes, radio buttons and buttons these all elements have a same class filterProducts. I am filtering the products and rendering them to the web page.
but he problem that I am facing is it is either calling a click event or change event, is there any solution for this problem?
Though I can assign a different class for each element and create a different block of code that will do the work, but I believe that it would increase the duplicacy.

```js
$(document).on('change click', '.filterProducts', function(e) { // This block of code is only working for click event.

  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
  }

  // Filter code goes here ...

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="filterProducts" name="operator" value="1" id="operator" />
<input type="radio" class="filterProducts" name="open_for_sale" value="1" />
<input type="radio" class="filterProducts" name="open_for_sale" value="0" />
<button type="button" class="pagination-button filterProducts" page="1">1</button>
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: As said by others, the change event is executed when clicking a radio or checkbox. Therefore you would only need the change event. Just remove the click event.

Comment: change event would not work for a button, that's what I am struggling in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a named function to attach the same function to multiple event handlers with different selectors.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input.filterProducts', filterProducts);
$(document).on('click', 'button.filterProducts', filterProducts);

function filterProducts(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.tagName);

    if( $(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Filter code goes here ...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="filterProducts" name="operator" value="1" id="operator" />
<input type="radio" class="filterProducts" name="open_for_sale" value="1" />
<input type="radio" class="filterProducts" name="open_for_sale" value="0" />
<button type="button" class="pagination-button filterProducts" page="1">1</button>
```